# Error in solve.default() : argument "a" is missing, with no default

Tags: r

```
makeCacheMatrix <- function(x = matrix()) {
  invm <- NULL
  set <- function(y) {
    x <<- y
    invm <<- NULL
  }
  get <- function() x
  setinverse <- function(solve) invm <<- solve()
  getinverse <- function() invm
  list(set = set, get = get,
       setinverse = setinverse,
       getinverse = getinverse)
}
```

```
cacheSolve <- function(x, ...) {
  invm <- x$getinverse()
  if(!is.null(invm)) {
    message("getting cached matrix")
    return(invm)
  }
  unit <- x$get()
  invm <- solve(unit, ...)
  x$setinverse(invm)
  invm
}
```

In the test run, I've created a 4/4 matrix which was then stored with the first function. The second function should check if the matrix is cached, if so, print a message and use the stored matrix. I'd like to know what could possibly cause the error displayed below. I have no idea why the data don't get passed to the solve function.

```
> test <- matrix(rnorm(16, 3), 4, 4)
> test
         [,1]     [,2]      [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 2.654912 4.085775 3.1288214 5.059539
[2,] 3.252612 3.403775 0.9990708 1.623138
[3,] 1.705998 3.586488 3.3337772 1.849144
[4,] 2.040830 4.815228 4.1713251 2.294179
> test2 <- makeCacheMatrix(test)
> cacheSolve(test2)
 Error in solve.default() : argument "a" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `x$setinverse(invm)`, you are passing in a `matrix` object. But in the function `setinverse`, you are calling its one argument as a function, using `solve()`. Unfortunately, while `solve` at that point refers to the *object* passed originally as `invm`, R is smart-enough to know that `solve()` is meant to use a *function* and therefore is referring to `base::solve` and not your matrix. If you run `base::solve()` you will get the same error. So your problem is that your `setinverse` is wrong.

If you instead assign `setinverse <- function(z) invm <<- solve(z)`, it seems to operate without error. **Edit**: actually, I think you're just using this as a "setter" function, so it should really be `setinverse <- function(solve) invm <<- solve` (or `function(z) invm <<- z`, your call).

**Note**: I haven't thought through the whole process to know if this is truly what you want to do.

Functions:

```r
makeCacheMatrix <- function(x = matrix()) {
  invm <- NULL
  set <- function(y) {
    x <<- y
    invm <<- NULL
  }
  get <- function() x
  setinverse <- function(z) invm <<- z
  getinverse <- function() invm
  list(set = set, get = get,
       setinverse = setinverse,
       getinverse = getinverse)
}
# cacheSolve as previously defined
```

Reproducible running (I suggest you use `set.seed` next time):

```r
set.seed(42)
test <- matrix(rnorm(16, 3), 4, 4)
test
#            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
# [1,] 4.37095845 3.40426832 5.01842371 1.61113930
# [2,] 2.43530183 2.89387548 2.93728590 2.72121123
# [3,] 3.36312841 4.51152200 4.30486965 2.86667866
# [4,] 3.63286260 2.90534096 5.28664539 3.63595040
test2 <- makeCacheMatrix(test)
cacheSolve(test2)
#              [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]
# [1,]  0.819557500  1.961377325 -1.416577665 -0.714220507
# [2,] -0.162978899 -0.332156840  0.713223804 -0.241513973
# [3,] -0.343049934 -1.761166112  0.897525201  0.762466368
# [4,] -0.189839546  0.866424154 -0.459528758  0.073008724
```

Answer (score 0):

It works! Thank you so much!
What I still don't get though is why the mean() function doesn't need this specification and still can refer to an object. Originally the code went like this:

```
makeVector <- function(x = numeric()) {
        m <- NULL
        set <- function(y) {
                x <<- y
                m <<- NULL
        }
        get <- function() x
        setmean <- function(mean) m <<- mean
        getmean <- function() m
        list(set = set, get = get,
             setmean = setmean,
             getmean = getmean)
}
```

```
cachemean <- function(x, ...) {
        m <- x$getmean()
        if(!is.null(m)) {
                message("getting cached data")
                return(m)
        }
        data <- x$get()
        m <- mean(data, ...)
        x$setmean(m)
        m
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer, Arrinao. The reason this works (`mean` is referring to the *object* and not the *function*) is because here you use `mean` and not `mean()`, as you did in the other example. Based on your comment here, it appears that my answer really should be `setinverse <- function(z) invm <<- z` instead of `solve(z)`.

Comment: Please delete this answer.

Comment: I don't really know how I am supposed to delete it. I can only see "delete" option on my posts:/
BTW. is there a way to contact you directly? I would like to ask some questions about my own experiments with this code and don't really want to clog this thread with it.